# openam token expiration timeout

Tags: passport.js, openam, passport-local

I am using openam for authentication in a web App, using rest API call,
using this

> curl \
>    --request POST \
>    --header "X-OpenAM-Username: demo" \
>    --header "X-OpenAM-Password: changeit" \
>    --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
>    --data "{}" \
>    https://openam-server.com:8443/openam/json/authenticate"

which return me a tokeId as output

> { "tokenId": "AQIC5w...NTcy*", "successUrl": "/openam/console"

I know there is an token api isTokenValid to check token is valid or not, but I require to get token expiration time, Is it possible to get tokenId expire time without using oAuth client,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had check in openam 12.0.0 provides  new session Information rest apis

This gives  determine whether a session is active or not based on tokenId

From openam 12 guide :

For these REST endpoints, specify two SSO tokens. Provide the SSO token for the current authenticated user as the value of a header whose name is the name of the SSO token cookie, by default iPlanetDirectoryPro. Specify the SSO token about which you want information as the tokenId query string parameter of the REST URL.

```
/openam/json/sessions/?_action=isActive&tokenId
```

To check the maximum remaining time (in seconds) of a session

```
/openam/json/sessions/?_action=getMaxTime&tokenId
```

check the amount of time (in seconds) that a session has been idle

```
/openam/json/sessions/?_action=getIdle&tokenId
```

for check token information I can use this  rest apis

Answer (score 0):

The json/authenticate endpoint is returning an OpenAM SSO token - not an OAuth2 access token. Is that what you want?

If you want an access token or a JWT, use the oauth2 endpoint:

```
   curl --request POST --data "grant_type=client_credentials&username=demo&password=password&client_id=test&client_secret=password&scope=cn%20mail%20profile%20openid" \
 http://openam.example.com:28080/openam/oauth2/access_token
```

The above gets an OIDC JWT token, but if you want an vanilla access token just drop the profile and openid scopes and ask for something else (mail, cn)

Comment: ok I am very new to this openAM concepts, I am using OpenAM SSOtoken only using rest api of openam which return me toked id, I want to know how do we check token is not expired, what if openAm token get expired, should I check every time tokenid valid or not.

Comment: You may check http://docs.forgerock.org/en/openam/11.0.0/dev-guide/index.html#rest-api-tokens

An agent would register a token listener to get a notification when the token is expired ... with REST you have to decide when you check for validity.